# SQL Query Cannot Update string from capital letter to lowercase

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a search and replace on my SQL database in phpMyAdmin. I'm updating the database from using a depreciated plugin called more-fields to ACF. The old meta_keys are all capitalised of have spaces in the string. To keep with ACF formatting I'm doing a quick search and replace to change the meta_keys. The SQL script worked for string with a space but I cannot seem to get it to find the rows when searching a string that is capitalised. I can see the meta_key in the table but the SQL command returns 0 when I simulate the query.

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key` = 'contact_name' WHERE 'meta_key’ = 'Contact Name'
```

This one worked fine. It found any row in the wp_postmeta table that contained the word 'Contact Name' and changed it to 'contact_name'

but...

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key` = 'county' WHERE `meta_key` = 'County';
```

Will not find any row that contains 'County' in the meta_key. Am I missing something stupid here? I can clearly see there are many rows which contain the word 'County" in its meta_key

Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Ok so I noticed if I replaced the capitalised word for _county it found and worked. So I then replaced the _county for county to complete it but why does SQL do this. Is there a way to replace the words from Capital to lowercase?

Comment: *Will not find any row that contains 'County' in the meta_key.* How you detect this?

Comment: Hi Akina, I can see the result in the phpMyAdmin interface. There is over 200 rows I need to change so doing it manually for a couple of tables was not an option.

Comment: I noticed you changed the quotes from one case to the other. However this should not be the issue. When you say it "contains he word" what do you mean? You query for equals, not for contains.

Comment: Please provide an example tuple, that contains the _County_ value, maybe as a screenshot from your result.

Comment: `WHERE meta_key LIKE '%County%'`?

Comment: Sorry lads the copy and paste changes the character encoding. LEt's assume the query runs ok. I've checked for spacing etc. It seems that the change from Capitalise word to Non capitalise word does not get recognised. The second I want to change the Capitalised word to something else it will recognise the word and change it. It's like it doesn't recognise a change when trying to run the query to update a capitalise word to non capitalised word.

Comment: *I can see the result in the phpMyAdmin interface.* This tells nothing. Execute the query in CLI and provide `Rows matched: XXX  Changed: YYY  Warnings: ZZZ` from the output.

Comment: SQL query:
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key` = 'county' WHERE `meta_key` = 'County'
Matched rows: 0

Comment: Yet. 

SQL query:
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key` = '_county' WHERE `meta_key` = 'County'
Matched rows: 349

Comment: @SebastianBrosch

SQL query:
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key` = 'county' WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%County%'
Matched rows: 0

Comment: Have you checked whether the _data_ did not actually change, or are you looking at the number of “matched rows” reported after the UPDATE statement only? I’m guessing this is a problem with a case-insensitive collation perhaps? If the database is instructed to view `County` and `county` as equal in comparisons, then it probably won’t report a change from `County` to `county` as an _actual_ change either …

Comment: Strange one. How i've done it to replace the word 'County' with '_county' and then run it again to replace '_county' with 'county'

just seems a bit of a workaround. I'm sure there is a way to replace 'County' with 'county' - but phpMyAdmin doesn't seem to recognise there is a difference.

Comment: Maybe you  should update it via the wordpress API, see: [Update query for wp_posts and wp_postmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238011/update-query-for-wp-posts-and-wp-postmeta) ?

Comment: Please try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'County';`. Do such rows even exist?

Comment: Also I want to add that I hope you **created a backup before trying out UPDATE statements**, as you might corrupt your database if something unexpected happens.

Comment: County or Count**r**y?

Comment: County - Same word just need to replace the capital version with the non capitalised version but SQL doesn't seem to recognise any change when running the query.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work:

```
 WHERE meta_key = 'County'
```

Then the exact match doesn't work.  One possibility -- if you see the value -- are hidden characters.  Does this return any results?

```
select meta_key
from wp_postmeta
where meta_key like '%County%';
```

If this returns exactly what you want, then you can just use the `like` condition for filtering.  If it returns additional keys, you can adjust the `like` pattern.